# Powershell output supression

Tags: powershell, psexec

Im trying to enable WinRM on remote machine using psexec + powershell, but it gives me an unwanted output that i cannot supress yet.

```
C:\psexec\PsExec64.exe -nobanner -accepteula \\computer1 powershell.exe Stop-Service winrm
```

And got this output that i want to supress:

```
C:\psexec\PsExec64.exe : Connecting to computer1...
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\psexec\PsExec64.exe -nobanner -accepteula \\computer1 powershell.exe  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Connecting to computer1...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Starting PSEXESVC service on computer1...
Connecting with PsExec service on computer1...
Starting powershell.exe on computer1...
powershell.exe exited on computer1 with error code 0.
```

I tried with normal powershell error handling but did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `&{ C:\psexec\... } *>$null`

Comment: +1 to Mathias' comment - if you would like to know more about output stream redirection you can have a look here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1#example-4-redirect-all-streams-to-a-file